# Where is the default index.jsp file in a Java EE project in NetBeans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I create a simple web application in NetBeans, named WebApplication1. There is a file created, named `index.jsp`. When I run the application, and the browser goes to `index.jsp`.

Nowhere in the project is it mentioned as the welcome page. Then how is  it going there?

I checked files *build.xml*, *glassfish-web.xml*, all XML files, and prop files in the *nbproject* folder, but nowhere is the mention of `index.jsp`. How is it taking?

Comment: Have you checked web.xml ?

Comment: Yes, no mention of anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In NetBeans by default, if you create a project with no added frameworks, no deployment descriptor (file *web.xml*) is provided.

To change it, right click on the project and select `New>Other>web>Standard Deployment Descriptor(web.xml)`.

Now edit the *web.xml* file and set

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>newjsp.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

in order to change the default to file *newjsp.jsp*.

Explicitly for [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)...

If no *web.xml* file is provided in the application, the default web.xml($CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml) of Tomcat is supplied to the application. This deployment descriptor has the following lines:

```xml
<!-- -->
<!-- If you define welcome files in your own application's web.xml -->
<!-- deployment descriptor, that list *replaces* the list configured -->
<!-- here, so be sure to include any of the default values that you wish -->
<!-- to use within your application. -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

That is why the *index.jsp* file is shown by default.

Comment: For http web servers it is index.html , are you sure if the web.xml doesn't have welcome-file-list defined , still the container will pick index.jsp ?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy So, the cause was Glassfish/Tomcat?

Comment: if nothing is added in web.xml and you have index.html and index.jsp it will pickup the html file

Comment: @The New Idiot please see my UPDATE

Comment: @PhilipRego it maybe not correct right now but you can understand what you really have to do right?

Comment: @PhilipRego As i see it in NB8.2 it is still the same. You right click on the project and select new>other>web>standard deployment descriptor (web.xml)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using NetBeans you need to click right the button on your project and then properties. A new pop up window will open, and on the left menu there will be a label called *Run*. Click there and then in the "relative URL". You should input:

```
./nameOfYourJspFile.jsp
```

And that's all!

Comment: This is great can you briefly tell me what that means ? And why I couldn't get the page to load by just using a <welcome-file>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the JSP code file is not in the Web-Inf directory. It should be in the Web Pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

It could be *index.html* or *index.jsp*, the welcome page of your web application in NetBeans.

Also there is also a bug in NetBeans IDE 8.2: even if you make changes in the descriptor *web.xml* file (by adding the "welcome-file-list" tag), "Run" runs the old version of your index!

To fix this, put './index.html' in the 'Relative URL' field in the category "Run" in properties of your project.