# index.jsp file opens even when the <welcome-file-list> is not defined

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

I've written a simple dynamic web project in Eclipse Luna. In web.xml page I've removed the default `welcome-file-list` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>indextest</display-name>
</web-app>
```

But the url http://localhost:8080/indextest/ still directs to `index.jsp` under 'WEB-INF' even after I've removed the tag `welcome-file-list` from `web.xml`. How it directs to `index.jsp` page though `welcome-file-list` is absent in `web.xml`?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Might be it was stored in you browser's cookies, just delete it retry it. Or else just clean you tomcat working directory that also create problem sometime.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat v7.0 >>> @Paolof76

Comment: OK I know the issue... let's explain in a post

Comment: Hey @RafafTahsin, I added also the info that u r using tomcat 7, it's good to know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Tomcat 7 instance, and are not specifying the welcome-file-list, the container (tomcat) is looking into his default, that is in /conf/web.xml in your tomcat instance.

These are the lines:

```
<welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>     
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
```

I suggest not to change anything in the tomcat default, because your web application should not be dependent on the container that runs it. Instead, you should define your own welcome-file-list in your own web.xml.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If there is no welcome list provided then the container will try to load the below files in the order defined:

1. index.html
2. index.htm
3. index.jsp

Update:
regarding tomcat

If no web.xml is provided in the application, the default web.xml($CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml) of Tomcat is supplied to the application. This deployment descriptor has the following lines:

```
<!-- -->
<!-- If you define welcome files in your own application's web.xml -->
<!-- deployment descriptor, that list *replaces* the list configured -->
<!-- here, so be sure to include any of the default values that you wish -->
<!-- to use within your application. -->

<welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>     
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
```

That is why the index.jsp is shown by default

Source for update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247947/1129313

Answer (score 0):

The default file will call `index.jsp` if you change The file name Then it will not found `index.jsp` and you can get as expected result.